# How to use submit button inside a php code to update record

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have a page that has a list of users in my database, every user is in a separated table, each table is having a button that can active the user, here are my codes

```
 <?php
     while($r =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryD))
            {           
     echo "<table width='800' border='0' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid black; outline: 3px solid #262626;' cellspacing='0px' cellpadding='2px;'>";
       echo "<tbody>";
         echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td width='193' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Username" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Name" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='98' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Phone" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='50' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Age" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='148' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Gender" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='160' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Natunality" . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";

         echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;
color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Username"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;
color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Name"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;
color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Phone"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='50' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;
color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Age"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;
color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Gender"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;
color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Natunality"] . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";

         echo "<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; text-align:right; padding: 0px;'>
           <form action='users.php' method='post'>
           <input type='submit' name='active' id='active' title='Active User' value='Active'>
           </form>
           </td>
           ";?>
```

and my query:

```
if(isset($_POST['active'])){

    $queryR = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET isAct=1");
    mysqli_close($con);

}
```

My problem is the button does nothing when I press it also, if the this code runs correctly will all the users in database have active value of 1? I want to update only the user that I pressed on, how can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a hidden field for holding ***user id or name***(**unique identifier for each record**) and on submit, collect the value of that respective row button and modify the SQL with where clause for updating that targeted record.

so your code should modified as below -

```
<?php
 while($r =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryD))
        {           
 echo "<table width='800' border='0' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid black; outline: 3px solid #262626;' cellspacing='0px' cellpadding='2px;'>";
   echo "<tbody>";
     echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td width='193' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Username" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Name" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='98' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Phone" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='50' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Age" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='148' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Gender" . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='160' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Natunality" . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";

     echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Username"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Name"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Phone"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='50' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Age"] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Gender"] . "</td>";
  echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black; background-color: #005B87;color: #FFFFFF;'>" . $r["Natunality"] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";

     echo "<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; text-align:right; padding: 0px;'>
       <form action='users.php' method='post'>
       <input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$r["id"].">
       <input type='submit' name='active' id='active' title='Active User' value='Active'>
       </form>
       </td>
       ";?>
```

and your updated php query action should be-

```
 if(isset($_POST['active'])){

    $queryR = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET isAct=1 WHERE id =".$_POST['id']);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If ypu are not going to that page users.php then I would suggest to call a function on click and pass the username of the current user through that function and then inside that function you can make $.ajax post request and send that user's name to users.php and then update that specific row

Comment: Sorry, just realized you are not using jquery
In php instead of sending data to that page just make a function inside this page and do the same thing inside it except put a condition on update to change the specific row